# AJAX - on button click does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, submit

as title suggests, I am having issues running my script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subbut").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
                    {
                        url : 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?email=Sincere@april.biz',
                        method : 'GET'
                    })
            .then(
                    function(data) {

                        document.getElementById("street").value = data[0].address.street;

                    });
    });
});
</script>
```

And my form is here:

```
<form id="myForm"
            action="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath()
                + "/upisKorisnika.html")%>"
            method="POST">
            <table id='userInput' class="display" border="0"
                style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px;">

                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="E-mail: " /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                        <input type="submit" name="subbut" class="btn btn-default" id="subbut" value="Submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" id="street" name="street" />
            </form>
```

My first question is why doesn't anything happen when I click submit, what am I doing wrong?
And I would also like to know how could I get value of text field "Email", so I could use something like this:

```
url : 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?email='+mail,
```

Answer (score 0):

First, is confusing the use of a form that not send data to the server and a submit button without submit form behavior.

Second you need use a debug tool like chrome developer tool. It will give you the trace of your calls.

To debug, add to the promise.then the error callback with a simple alert or a console.log to view what is happen with your call.

And responding your question,your code seen be right.